# How can I set the preserveWorldVelocity flag in Gazebo 9 (hopefully through roslaunch and urdf)?

Tags: ros-kinetic, gazebo-7, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In order to get rid of [unwanted behavior in Gazebo 7](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues/612), I have installed Gazebo 9 in hopes of setting the preserveWorldVelocity flag.  (Is "flag" the proper term?)  I'm using roslaunch and xacro to start my simulation.  In the robot xacro I have

```
<gazebo>
  <self_collide>1</self_collide>
</gazebo>
```

but trying something similar with

```
<preserveWorldVelocity>1</preserveWorldVelocity>
```

has no effect.  Can you tell me how to set this flag so that using PositionJointInterface does not mean velocities are repeatedly cleared?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18708/how-can-i-set-the-preserveworldvelocity-flag-in-gazebo-9-(hopefully-through-roslaunch-and-urdf)?/) by [raequin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2401/raequin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 165 on 2018-03-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The solution is to install the latest version of gazebo_ros_pkgs from source (http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_installing&cat=connect_ros).  With that package _preserveWorldVelocity is true.

---

Originally posted by [raequin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2401/raequin/) with karma: 165 on 2018-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0